# So what does the function SDL_FreeSurface do?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I checked the definition of this function, but I'm still not very clear about it, explain it to me in a simple sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the opposite of the `SDL_Create___Surface` functions -- it tells the system that it no longer needs to keep the resources (memory, etc) associated with the `SDL_Surface*` you pass it. It is the equivalent to `delete` or `free` for the more complicated `SDL_Surface` structure. This is a common pattern in C libraries (in C++, we would encapsulate freeing a resource in the destructor for that class).

Comment: Now I'm clear, so do you have to use SDL_FreeSurface if you used SDL_CreateSurface before, I mean is that necessary?

Comment: Yes. If you do not use `SDL_FreeSurface`, then you have a memory leak and will eventually run out of memory. In a similar manner, use of `malloc` without `free` will eventually cause problems.

Comment: got it! Thank you for your help!